# How to exit from a Powershell inline command with the return value of the last function?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a function in a powershell module which display messages and return $true.

This following command in a MSDOS console works. I see all messages of the function on the standard output and I return the hard coded value $true :

```
C:>Powershell -NoProfile -Command "& {Import-Module MyModule; MyFunctionInModule -Parameter1 'D:\...'; exit $true }"
C:>echo %errorlevel%
1
```

But how to exit with the return value of the function ? This following command doesn't work. I don't see the output messages of the function and I don"t get the return value of the function :

```
C:>Powershell -NoProfile -Command "& {Import-Module MyModule; $result = MyFunctionInModule -Parameter1 'D:\...'; exit $result }"
C:>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First this works for me in PowerShell 2.0

```
C:\>Powershell -NoProfile -Command "& {write-host "coucou";$return=13;  exit $return}"
coucou

C:\Users\BLANCJP>echo %errorlevel%
13
```

For me the reason why it does not work for you is that in your function `MyFunctionInModule` you are using `write-output` to write to the console. Everything you put un write-output in your function create an array wich is the return of your function. So use Write-Host to write to the host in your function and juste return XX at the end of the function and it should work.